# How to add attribute in TR and TD?

Tags: datatables

I want to add row using data datatables, and I can do it like this

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();
table.add.row(['first column', 'second column', 'three column', 'etc']);
```

What I need is something like this (some attribute in TR and TD tag)

```
<tr id="someID">
<td>first column</td>
<td>second column</td>
<td>three column</td>
<td id="otherID">etc</td>
</tr>
```

How I can do it with datatables?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) and [`columns.createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) options to define a callback function that will be called when `TR` and `TD` element are created.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  'createdRow': function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
      $(row).attr('id', 'someID');
  },
  'columnDefs': [
     {
        'targets': 3,
        'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
           $(td).attr('id', 'otherID'); 
        }
     }
  ]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/h4qpv9zc/10/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: thanks @Gyrocode.com in your example data loaded via AJAX, what about if I add row manually like my example?

Comment: @DarkCyber, it should not matter, however I updated the example to use `row.add()`.

Answer (score -2):

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData) {
    var $nRow = $(nRow);
    $title = `Detalles de la Orden No. ${aData['noOrden']}`;
    $nRow.attr("title", $title);

    return nRow;
  },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Also, why is this answer even necessary when there is already an accepted answer? [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)