# how to add data-attributes to the rows of a JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I would like to had (multiple) data-attributes to the generated rows of my JQuery DataTable so that I can store data in it.

What I want to achieve is to make DataTables generate something like this:

```
<tr data-foo="bar">
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Is it possible? How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add attribute in TR and TD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625983/how-to-add-attribute-in-tr-and-td)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So I found out, what I needed was to set my attributes dynamically, it's possible using the data parameter of the function, it contains the model corresponding to the row.

```
    var table = $('#incidentTable').DataTable({
        createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {
            $(row).attr('data-id', data.Id);
            $(row).attr('data-ownerid', data.OwnerId);
        }
    });
```