# Adding data-* attrributes to jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I able to add id to each row of data table using `rowId` ,as explained in [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId).

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: '/api/staff',
    rowId: 'staffId'
} );
```

But how do I add data-* attributes to the row.

For example I want to have add data-spaceid and ata-enrollmentid to the row.

```
<tr data-spaceid="20146" data-enrollmentid="32" id="123"/>
```

Comment: Maybe by this way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625983/how-to-add-attribute-in-tr-and-td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow), Callback for whenever a TR element is created for the table's body to add data attribute. Here is an example.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
  'createdRow': function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
      $(row).attr('data-spaceid', '20146');
  },
});
```