# Get value from a C# variable for datatables attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, datatables

I fetch some values from an external source using a C# function (File.aspx.cs) and use this value as an [custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625983/how-to-add-attribute-in-tr-and-td) on datatables. However I only get 0,1,2 etc as the ID value and not the real value from the C# dataID variable, eventhough I already use `var ID = '<%=dataID%>';` on my JS file (without quote I got error (JS) Expression expected).

How do I get this dataID value on my dt.file.js?

**File.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Example : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static int dataID;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static DataTableResponse GetList(string parameters)
    {
        DataTableAjaxPostModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTableAjaxPostModel>(parameters);
        List<FieldAgentRow> list = new List<FieldAgentRow>();

        XmlDocument doc = Utilities.FileToXmlDocument("data");

        foreach (XmlNode person in doc.SelectNodes("//Personal"))
        {
            FieldAgentRow tmp = new FieldAgentRow();

            //other codes

            tmp.data_id = Int32.Parse(person.SelectSingleNode("ID").InnerText);
            dataID = tmp.data_id;

            list.Add(tmp);
        }

        DataTableResponse res = new DataTableResponse();
        res.draw = model.draw;
        res.data = list;

        return res;
    }
}
```

**dt.file.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ID = '<%=dataID%>';
    var table = $('#list').DataTable({
        "createdRow": function (row, data, ID ) {
            $(row).attr('data-id', ID);
        }
        //other codes
    });
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION:**
Thanks to [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51705474/9360197), I am able to take the data_id value by modifying my JS code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#list').DataTable({
        "createdRow": function (row, data, dataindex) {
            $(row).attr('data-id', data.data_id);
        }
        //other codes
    });
```

Comment: Is it me or your `GetList` doesn't *`return`* anything?

Comment: @Rafalon I added the missing part. It is not the interesting part though, because I want to focus only on the variable

Comment: You need to use the data property to get tot he json for the row in your createdRow method https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow. You should be able to do data.data_id (assuming the property name is not changed during serialization).  You can also do console.log(data) there and examine it in your browser dev tools (f12) to see what properties are available.

Comment: @PaulZepernick It works! That's actually much more simpler than I thought. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: BTW, if you are just trying to assign a unique id to the row you can send the json property DT_RowId in your row.  If you are using DT 1.10.8 > it appears there is an option to change the default name https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the data property to get to the json for the row in your createdRow method  https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow. You should be able to do data.data_id (assuming the property name is not changed during serialization)..

You can also do console.log(data) there and examine it in your browser dev tools (f12) to see what properties are available.